# Synology DSM4.3 with Kerberos and NFSv4

Tags: network-attached-storage, nfs, kerberos

According to the press releases of Synology DSM4.3 can do NFSv4 and Kerberos. Actually, in the Tab with NFS settings, there is a button for Kerberos settings. But I cannot find any guidance anywhere.

I have a KDC running on a seperate host. I want the NAS to authenticate users using this KDC - ideally it would read the principals from the LDAP, which is setup already to supply user names and groups.

Does anyone have experience how to do that or at least has seen a HOWTO, documentation, ... anything beyond a press release?

Comment: Based on my experience at my workplace, Synology can become an LDAP client and use the LDAP information for login credentials (username and password). It is located under Control Panel - Directory Services - LDAP. Just need your LDAP server details. Just give it a try and enter your LDAP details. If it fails you still can login using the 'local' synology username and password.

Comment: LDAP seems to work. At least I see users and groups. But my LDAP does not store any valid passwords, but principal names. Authentication is done via Keberos in my infrastructure.

Comment: There is an entry for Kerberos in "DSM Help" under "NFS Service" - If you open DSM Help and search for Kerberos, NFS Service has some information about mapping Kerberos Principals to local user accounts, with a note below it to map kerberos to existing domain/LDAP account. Hope that helps.

Comment: I have DSM4.3, there is no Kerberos button in the NFS tab in the Win/MAC/NFS screen under the Control Panel. Did you have to activate that?